# Why does Throwable.getCause check to see if 'cause' is 'this' before returning `null` instead of just returning the cause directly?

Tags: java, exception

I had a reason to go into the source code for `Throwable.getCause` today and was a little surprised to see this code in that method:

```
    public synchronized Throwable getCause() {
        return (cause==this ? null : cause);
    }
```

This is from Java 1.8, but it looks the same in the later versions I've looked at.

My question is: why not simply `return cause` and be done with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code:

```
 public synchronized Throwable getCause() {
     return (cause==this ? null : cause);
 }
```

Says if the `cause` is `this` return `null` otherwise return `cause` (which may also be `null` as it happens.

The story starts with this: `private Throwable cause = this;` which is I believe the same in all versions >=1.4. That initialises the cause to being this object!

The intention is that `Throwable` objects are immutable but it provides a method `void initCause(Throwable cause)` that can only be called once  to initialise the cause or cause initialised by a constructor.

As the documentation explains that allows the chaining of causes to sub-classes added before `cause` was introduced that don't include it in one of their constructors.

So the class somehow wants to know if `initCause` has been called and throws `IllegalStateException` if it has (my comments):

```
public Throwable initCause(Throwable cause) {
    if (cause == this) //Illogical! An exception can't be self caused!
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (this.cause != this)// false if cause has been initialised 'properly'.
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    this.cause = cause;
     return this;
}
```

The class is using `cause==this` to indicate `cause` not set.
It can't use `cause==null` because `null` is a valid value. So it uses the anomalous state of `cause==this` because actively setting `cause` to `this` is the illogical state of a self-caused exception.

It works, sure. But is it really a good idea?
I'm saying not. It conflates the states of "cause not set" and "cause has been set and is set to `null`".
A less contorted design just introduces a flag `private boolean isCauseSet=false;` and setting it if `initCause` is ever called or a constructor that sets it is called.

The convoluted code we see in `Throwable` achieves nothing more than avoiding a `boolean`.
Saving a single `boolean` field inside `Throwable` really doesn't seem worth the bother.
No useful application will ever have so many `Throwable` objects in circulation for it to matter.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't comparing `cause` to `null`, it's comparing `cause` to `this`. To avoid circles, if `cause` is `this`, it returns null.

Comment: As the question as originally stated is obviously stupid, I thought of deleting it. Instead, I think I will edit the question to make it more useful to anyone who might read it later.

Comment: I'm going to award the "answer" to @Persixty as that answer explains *why* this is done, even though bmargulies answered the original question correctly. Persixty's answer has a complete explanation of the reason for this check.

Answer (score 1):

This `null` value is used by `printStackTrace` method [e.g. when calling `stackTraceString` method, lines 421..450](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/Throwable-source.html) to identify when the output of the stack trace should be finished.